# oralce 11g Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Tags: java-8, oracle11g, ojdbc

1. springBootVersion 2.0.6.RELEASE
2. JDK 1.8.0_202
3. Oracle (ver. Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
   With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options)

```
dependencies {
...
implementation('com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.4.0-atlassian-hosted')
...
}
```

```
datasource:
  url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxx:1521:gnnt
  username: xxxxx
  password: xxxxx
  driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  # HikariCP settings
  hikari:
    connection-timeout: 60000
    maximum-pool-size: 5
```

The project has been running stably for two months.
Tested this morning and found

```
2024-01-12 08:25:23.829 ERROR 1 --- [http-nio-9002-exec-6] b.m.a.RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler : member error：
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:450)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:474)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:289)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy193.findById(Unknown Source)
    cn.boce.member.service.impl.IMgrSettingsServiceImpl.getMgrSettingsByKey(IMgrSettingsServiceImpl.java:24)
    cn.boce.member.controller.inner.TMgrSettingsController.getMgrSettingsByKey(TMgrSettingsController.java:42)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor364.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155)
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123)
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I did not find any existing links by checking the database connection status

Comment: "Unable to acquire JDBC Connection" Make sure that the server you are connecting to is: working; running an Oracle instance; and accepting connections. Make sure your firewall allows outbound connections as well.